# How would we punctuate a sentence which ends in an abbreviation and exclamation mark or question mark?

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, question-mark

I was wondering what to do if I have abbreviation at the end of a sentence which ends in a question mark.

> What is Google inc.?

> What is Google inc.

> What is Google inc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the question mark, even if you have a period before: "What is google inc.?"

Answer (score 3):

You need to write both. The first example is correct: What is Google Inc.?